# PHP - Remove siblings (leaf) which are the same from an array (remove same arrays from array)

Tags: php, arrays

Trying to remove same siblings (leafs)/same arrays from nested array.

e.g

```
$data = [
        'test' => [
                'a' => [
                        'b' => 'something',
                        5 => [
                                'a' => [
                                        1 => 'test1',
                                        19 => 'test2',
                                        6 => 'test3',
                                ],
                                0 => 'test',
                        ],
                ],
                'b' => 1,
                2 => [
                        3 => 'something',
                        5 => 'somethingelse',
                ],
                4 => 'body'
        ],
        'anothertest' => [
                'b' => 1,
                0 => [
                        'test' => 1,
                        2 => 'something',
                        3 => 'somethingelse',
                ],
                1 => [
                        'test' => 1,
                        2 => 'something',
                        3 => 'somethingelse',
                ],
        ],
];

Array
(
    [test] => Array
        (
            [a] => Array
                (
                    [b] => something
                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [a] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => test1
                                    [19] => test2
                                    [6] => test3
                                )

                            [0] => test
                        )

                )

            [b] => 1
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [3] => something
                    [5] => somethingelse
                )

            [4] => body
        )

    [anothertest] => Array
        (
            [b] => 1
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [test] => 1
                    [2] => something
                    [3] => somethingelse
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [test] => 1
                    [2] => something
                    [3] => somethingelse
                )

        )

)
```

$data['anothertest'][0] and $data['anothertest'][1] are the same, so one has to be removed.

Arrays with string indexes can be skipped.

Bumped how to compare one array to another in foreach key value block.

I Know I can compare same array with `===` operator, but don't know how can I access next one in foreach loop.

Here is my code, with PSUEDOCODE block which I don't know how to do.

```
function cleansiblings($array)
  {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                if (!is_string($key)) {
                   //PSEUDO CODE 
                   //compare current $value to $value+1?? 
                }
    }

  }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried array_unique function?
 (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove duplicates from multi-dimensional array like this

```
<?php

function get_unique($array){
    $result = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));
    foreach ($result as $key => $value){
        if ( is_array($value) ){
            $result[$key] = get_unique($value);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

echo "<pre/>";print_r(get_unique($data));

?>
```

Output:-https://eval.in/817099

Comment: @android_dev  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

To answer just the last part of your question: You can access original $array in foreach loop using $key:

```
function cleansiblings($array)
  {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if (!is_string($key)) {
               if (isset($array[$key+1])) {
                  // Compare $array[$key] (or $value, it is the same) with $array[$key+1]
                  // To remove item from array, just unset it: unset($array[$key]). 
                  // Note that you can alter iterated array in PHP, 
                  // but not in some other languages.
               }
            }
    }

}
```